# Passing a function from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a function that take in a string, and convert it to a Mac Address format.

```
    function mac_adress($str){
        $end = substr($str, -12);
        $chunks = str_split($end, 2);
        $result = implode(':', $chunks);
        return $result;
    }
```

I want pass function to my view so I can just call it like this

`$str = 836997595163;`

`{!!mac_adress($str)!!} //83:69:97:59:51:63`

I have multiple views that need this functionally, and I'm trying to avoid place them in every single one of my blade file.

How can I do that ?

**Is it even possible ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a good candidate for a `helper`, depending on how much you really need the functionality throughout your site.

create a helpers.php file

```
<?php

function mac_adress($str){
     $end = substr($str, -12);
     $chunks = str_split($end, 2);
     $result = implode(':', $chunks);
     return $result;
 }
```

And then autoload it in `composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

then run `composer dump-autoload` in your terminal, and your helpers methods will be available throughout your application. Doing it this way, you can add more helper functions to `helpers.php` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it as a session variable, and call it as many times and many places needed

```
$_SESSION['mac-address'] = mac_address($str);
```

More information here [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Also you can use laravels session library [Laravel Session](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session)

Comment: Mine is a function though, can I do that ?

Comment: My bad, look at my edited answer. You can save the value returned by that function.

Comment: You should not answer if you do not understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Export it to a service class from where you can call it easily from every view

```
<?php $formatedMacAddress = \App\Services\MacAddressHelper::formatMacAdress($macAddress);?>


<div>{{ $formatedMacAddress }}</div>
```

```php
namespace \App\Services;

class MacAddressHelper
{
    public static function formatMacAdress(string $macAddress)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another clean way of doing this is through extending blade (utilizing @dtj's answer):

Create a helpers.php file:

```
// app/helpers.php

function macAddress($str) {
    $end = substr($str, -12);

    $chunks = str_split($end, 2);

    $result = implode(':', $chunks);

    return $result;
}
```

Edit your composer.json file:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Run `composer dump-autoload`

In AppServiceProvider:

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('mac', function($expression) {
        return "<?php echo macAddress{$expression}; ?>";
    });
}
```

Then in your views:

```
@mac('836997595163')
```

This way you can modify the helper function at any time and have a single reference to it.

Comment: That's kind of cool. Thank-you for sharing that with all of us. :)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested in a solution how to pass a function to a view (which is only used inside this view):

In your controller:

```php
/* ... */
public function getTestOverview()
   return view('test', [
      'mac_adress' => function($str) { return $this->mac_adress($str); }
   ]);
}

private function mac_adress($str){
   $end = substr($str, -12);
   $chunks = str_split($end, 2);
   $result = implode(':', $chunks);
   return $result;
}
/* ... */
```

In your view:

```php
{{ $mac_adress('foo') }}
```